# I want to check if my internet connection is active or not continuously with warning for whole app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check my internet connection in flutter app. I want to show a warning throughout the app, on any page. Is it possible to show a bottom or top warning when internet is not active, and when it becomes active again, warning should turn green with text "Internet is Active" and disappear after a few seconds. I don't want to use `connectivity_plus` on each and every page and check connection every time someone lands on that page. If there can be a central solution, which can be implemented inside main, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example code that solves your problem.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bot_toast/bot_toast.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();

}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  late StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> subscription;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {

      //display the network status to the user
      if(result == ConnectivityResult.none){
        BotToast.showSimpleNotification(title: "You are not connected to any network");
      }

    });
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "App Test",
      builder: BotToastInit(),
      home: FirstPage(),
    );
  }

}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("First page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage())),
          child: Text(
            "second page"
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("second page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage())),
          child: Text(
            "Back"
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Link to the article on the issue](https://flutter-love.com/gestion-efficace-de-la-connectivite-internet-dans-les-applications-flutter/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).